# How to gather stats of accessed file, true http

Tags: nginx, http, statistics

I have a simple file/web server. On that server I have files which are accessed by myself and others, using a URL.

It is on Ubuntu 14.4 server with nginx.

I want to know how many times a file was accessed. Like a list of all accessed files x times of x period of time.

How can I do this (preferably Open Source / Free Software)?

Comment: So basically what you want is a parser for `access.log` (assuming apache)? Enter 'access.log parser' on a search engine of your choice

Comment: maybe yes, not sure, checking out your suggestion now on google, I had a software that did some management and there I could always see how many times a file was accesed, but that software is gone, files are still in use, so I want to be able to easylie fast to see what files are still being used daily, sothat I can timely remove older files that nobody access anymore.

Comment: All of the info will be in the logs. You may want to reduce it, but the info is there. Tell us if you found what you are looking for.

Comment: Not yet, many log parsers, but didnot find one that gathers statistical data on accesed files. still searching.